# client side server side templating nodejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, backbone.js, client-side-templating

I am working on a webapp using nodejs. I was originally going to just server side hbs template, but then I found out about backbone for client side templating. I found out it can fetch data from server then display it using hbs template, instead of server side generate entire html page and send. But then I also read somewhere people suggest that it is not good practice to have many ajax calls in client side to get data and display for one webpage, it would have so many request to server, and the page would appear to be slow.  so I am wondering is there general rule how many requests can be made for one page? Should I use classic one request one respond? or should the respond be some client side javascript which then fetch data from server and display them ?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, there is no such general rule or best practice. Just ensure that when you are sending ajax requests, you do so efficiently. No synchronous calls, and send them in parallel if at all possible. Also make heavy use of caching.

Comment: it all depends on what you're doing and how you're doing it. people like gmail because it does many ajax calls on one page, and they like craigslist because it doesn't...

Comment: in most cases its just 1-3 more requests (getting the html,css & javascript as usual and populate the html with an extra json request) After that your one-page site will only make 1 request when you navigate back "home" to get fresh data

Comment: I recommend considering your audience and what you would like your application to do, and then doing server side and/or client side templating. Client side templating can be great for user experience, though it's important that you don't make too many requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the best solution is to render your templates server side and then have your Backbone app attach itself to the elements rendered by the server. I use Jade as my template engine, which allows me to reuse the templates server-side and client-side. You should spend sometime reading this **[link](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/11/30/rendering-on-the-server-and-client-in-node-dot-js/)**. If you decide this is what you are looking for, then install the app **[here](http://ezeljs.com/)**.

I find the above solution the least opinionated. You can also read through the code extremely quickly and get an idea behind the project. It's just a bunch of different technologies brought together, that help leverage the best in terms of client and server code reusability. Even the perceptive performance is drastic when rendering on the server side. You also get the added benefit of progressive enhancement and solve any issues you would with SEO and single page apps.